# How to run multiple php scripts parallel efficiently using apache server on linux

Tags: php, linux, apache, curl

Currently I'm using php multi_curl to run multiple php scripts parallel.

I've noticed that this method uses a lot of memory and cpu.

My questions:

1. Is there another method that is more efficient to run a large number of php scripts simultaneously? Or should I just upgrade the server?
2. Is there any chance that some changes in the configuration of php or apache lead to a better performance?

Comment: `multi_curl` indicates a webserver and all it's overhead. Can you eliminate that from the equasion? Just cli scripts & forking, or gearman and the like, might use a lot less resources.

Comment: I have to send parameters to the script too, would that be possible for those methods?

Comment: Yep, either by `STDIN`, or by command line arguments (found in `$argv`). In case of gearman, it is actually all about a function call wil arguments...

Answer (score 1):

You could use Gearman to start parallel tasks with parameters you decide to pass them